# SQL group rows based on overlapping ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have couple of signals, which turn on and off on random times of the day.
How can I select for all of them how they went on and off in general, so I can get the overlapped picture. In the image bellow we have the column signal_id(1,2) and for each one we have rows with start_datetime, end_datetime. We need the outcome in red in the image.

[image]

DB:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Please set up the data as a db<>fiddle, if you would like to see a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a gaps-and-islands problem.  This is a very general case, so I would recommend using a cumulative max to determine if there are overlaps:

```
select min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date then 0 else 1 end) over (order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_date) over (order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: How would you solve the opposite (instead of adding the overlap to subtract second from the first)? For example:

https://gyazo.com/d2f84e74c6f34fb83006d91a55a90005

Comment: @f14ka . . . A new question should be asked as a *new* question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag` and `sum` analytical function as follows:

```
select min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date then 0 else 1 end) 
                over (order by start_date) as sm
      from (select t.*,
                   Lag(end_date) over (order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from your_table t
           ) t
      ) t
group by sm;
```

Courtesy: Gordon, as used his query to create the new one.